# MATLAB Need help using 2D index table (look up table?)

Tags: matlab, matrix, lookup-tables

I create some sort of an index table that lists the row-index of another 2D matrix that the program needs to pull out and do some calculation.

For example, MATRIX 1 is a 3x3 containing numbers
[A, B, C; D, E, F; G, H, I]

and MATRIX 2 is another matrix size 5x5

So, I'd like to pull out the rows from MATRIX 2 using information in MATRIX 1 and do some calculation:

i.e. to sum the different of MATRIX 2 row # 1 with MATRIX 2 row #A, B, and C.
row 2 with row D,E,F of MATRIX 2
and row 3 with row G, H, I.

I'm not really sure how to do this (except using the for loop).The matrices in my code are very large (49x111600 and 111600x25). And for loops take a very long time.

---

Add details:

This is pretty much what I'd like to do:

```
s=0;

for i = 1: size(matrix1,2)

    for j = 1: size(matrix1,1)

    % using matrix1 as index for rows in matrix 2

        if matrix1(j,i) > 0,

            d = matrix2(i,:)-matrix2(matrix1(j,i),:);

            s(i) = s(i) + sum(d.^2);

        end

    end

end
```

But this takes a very long time with 2 for loops since my data is very large.

Comment: You say to sum the difference of row 1 of Matrix 2, is that just a number? and you want to add this to every element of row 1 of Matrix 1? You need to be very specific about the operation you wish to do.

Comment: You mean do something with `MATRIX2(1,:)` and `MATRIX2(MATRIX1(1,:),:)`? Can you give us an example?

Comment: You can do mathematical operations between matrixes,. IE: `Something=Matrix1(1,:)+Matrix2(5,:)`Be carefull that you need to have matrixes of same size while doing those sort of operations... Clarify what you need to do and we can help you further. (ninjaed by @beaker)

Comment: Thanks. I just added more details of what I'd like to do. I feel that there should be a way to avoid the loops, but not sure how...

Comment: You're overwriting `diff(i,:)` with the calculation for each row index in `matrix1`. Did you mean to create a 3d matrix? (Also, it's a horrible idea to create a variable with the same name as a built-in function.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I don't really need to store the values for diff (this could just be a vector that its values change in every loop). I just need this diff to get the sum. (I change the "diff" in the details to just "d"). And s would be just a vector with the same number of rows in matrix1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, are you sure you need to add `sum(d.^2)` to `s(i)` even when you are not computing anything at the iterations when `matrix1(j,i)<=0`?
I am assuming not. Also, I am hoping that `matrix1` is sparse.

---

The idea is to

1. first extract the indices to matrix2 all at once,
2. then only do the row subtractions all at once,
3. and finally do the column summation.

---

1. To get the indices, you may use:

   `[idcs_j, idcs_i] = find(matrix1>0);`
2. Then do the subtraction by accessing `matrix2` something like this:

`d = matrix2(idcs_i(:),:)-matrix2(matrix1((size(matrix1,1)*(idcs_i(:)-1)+idcs_j(:))),:);`

3. Now aggregate them as something like this:

`d = sum(d.^2, 2);`

`l = length(idcs_i);`

`s = sparse(idcs_i(:), ones(l,1), d, size(matrix1, 2), 1);`

`clear idcs_i idcs_j l d`

Check if the above is exactly correct? OR else correct it.

---

Explanation:

In step **one**, you are extracting the indices `(i,j)` in `matrix1` for which you want to sum in `matrix2`. (Now this step is as simple as this.)

In step **two**, you are extracting the corresponding rows in `matrix2` (see it as `idcs_i(k)` corresponds to `matrix1((size(matrix1,1)*(idcs_i(k)-1)+idcs_j(k)))` where `(size(matrix1,1)*(idcs_i(k)-1)+idcs_j(k)))` is the converted 1-d index location from 2-d).

In step **three**, `d = sum(d.^2, 2)` is doing your `sum(d.^2)` and `s = sparse(idcs_i(:), ones(l,1), d, size(matrix1, 2), 1)` is just doing your `s(i) = s(i) + *`. In fact, I have used `sparse(*)` function only to do the summation. and `s` will very likely end up as a fully dense vector. (Actually, sparse function accumulates values with same `(i,j)` indices. So, its just a trick even to be used with dense `matrix1` and `matrix2`.)

Comment: Oh, that s should be inside the if statement. Thanks! I'm not really sure about sparse. I read about it on MATLAB page and still could not get a good concept on it. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: Let's understand using an example. Consider an `integer` matrix of size `1000X1000`. Now, suppose your matrix has lot of `zero` elements and say has only 100 `non-zero` elements. namely, say `(1,2), (1,17), (26,300), etc.` Then if you store only the 100 `non-zero` elements with their  locations `(i,j)`. You only need to store `3X100=300` integers in the `memory` in `uncompressed` form. So you save `1000X1000-300` integer sized memory. That's it.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to play around a bit with the code to get a better understanding on step two and sparse matrix :)